# Serializing Lists of Objects with Jackson: "deep" and/or "shallow"

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

When serializing Lists of Objects with Jackson I would like to control whether the Object is serialized “deep” or “shallow”.

For Example: Test has two lists of class X objects

```
public class Test {
    public List<X> list1;
    public List<X> list2;

    public Test() {
        X x1 = new X("1", "one");
        X x2 = new X("2", "two");

        list1 = new LinkedList<X>();
        list1.add(x1);
        list1.add(x2);
        list1.add(x1);

        list2 = new LinkedList<X>();
        list2.add(x1);
        list2.add(x2);
    }
}

public class X {
    public String id;
    public String name;

    public X(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If serialized as is it will look like this:

```
{
"list1":[{"id":"1","name":"one"},{"id":"2","name":"two"},{"id":"1","name":"one"}],
"list2":[{"id":"1","name":"one"},{"id":"2","name":"two"}]
}
```

But say I wanted to serialize it so that list1 is a shallow version of X and list2 is a deep version of X:

```
{
"list1":["1","2","1"],
"list2":[{"id":"1","name":"one"},{"id":"2","name":"two"}]
}
```

Is there any annotation in Jackson that would do that for me? A custom serialize maybe? that Anything I can do to get me close to this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out (I think).

```
public class Test {
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id") @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    public List<X> list1;

    public List<X> list2;
```